# tomcat hangs when deploying war file and restarting server

Tags: tomcat, grails

When I build a .war file and deploy it to tomcat, tomcat will hang when I restart the server. I'm unable to SSH in and check the processes taking place. The admin here had to force reboot tomcat to solve the problem, and everything works great after that. This is the second time this has happened. Could someone point me in the right direction to troubleshoot this problem? I've checked all of tomcats logs, and I couldn't find anything helpful.

Comment: "restart the server" meaning the machine or restarting the tomcat process?
did you stop tomcat before putting the new war file into the webapps dir? or how did you deploy it? (via tomcat web-ui or autodeploy via webapps folder)

Comment: the admin had to do a hard restart of the server because she couldn't get a working terminal. To answer your other questions, I will deploy the tomcat file using FTP and then shutdown/restart the server using putty

Comment: no, I did not shutdown tomcat when I moved the file into the webapps dir, only after I moved it into there. The application will autodeploy using webapps

Comment: the way we always do it is first stop tomcat (via ssh or however your infrastructure looks like) then switch out the .war file (delete the expanded directories if that is enabled in your tomcat - if he creates a ROOT folder for ROOT.war) and then restart tomcat. The reason is that you can easily run into memory leaks otherwise (when certain classes cannot be unloaded etc.)

Comment: make that an answer, and I'll mark it correct if it works next time I deploy

Answer (score 6):

The way we always do our grails deploys is:

- stop tomcat (and wait until it actually stopped)
- delete the old .war file (and possibly the expanded directory: if tomcat expands `ROOT.war` to `./ROOT` )
- optional: delete/move old log files
- copy the new .war file into the webapps folder
- start tomcat

The reason is that you can easily run into memory leaks if you don't stop tomcat before, e.g. when certain classes cannot be unloaded etc.

Comment: This is our process exactly as well.