# Tomcat9 does not respond

Tags: tomcat, tomcat9, ajp

We have a strange issue since upgrading from tomcat8 to tomcat9.

- From time to time tomcat9 does not respond anymore.
- All deployed war applications are not reachable anymore.
- That being said the apache proxy server seems to be ok.
- Only restarting the tomcat9 service helps.

There are no helpful log entries in catalina.out or other app log files.

Our very only suspicion is that it occurs mainly when hot deploying war files (moving war files to the apps folder without stopping/starting tomcat9). In contrast - hot deploying was never a problem on tomcat8.

Maybe this is an ajp issue?
Here is our connector config:

```
<Connector
        port="8009"
        protocol="org.apache.coyote.ajp.AjpNio2Protocol"
        acceptCount="200"
        acceptorThreadCount="2"
        address="0.0.0.0"
        connectionTimeout="1800000"
        maxThreads="400"
        minSpareThreads="20"
        secretRequired="false"
        redirectPort="8443" />
```

I found some (maybe) related issue here: [tomcat hangs when deploying war file and restarting server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21704909/tomcat-hangs-when-deploying-war-file-and-restarting-server)

The folks over there state that they stop the tomcat, deploy the war, then start the tomcat again.

Anyone with the same issue since upgrading to tomcat9?

Comment: From tomcat 9 migration guide: `default listen address of the AJP Connector was changed to the loopback address rather than all addresses.`. Also, can you access port 8080 from localhost? is shutdown port usable and responsive (8005 usually)?

Comment: Thank you. Do you mean port 8443 instead of 8080? Since we are redirecting to https ...

Comment: Is port 8080 also opened regardless of 8443? If so, try connecting to it or try to shutdown tomcat on port 8005. Both to know if tomcat is really hanged.

Comment: For security reasons we don´t want to open up ports 8080 and 8005. We only have open ajp port (8009)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So it seems that the hot deployment on tomcat9 is somehow causing the freeze. The last three deployments were done like the following:

- stop tomcat9 service
- move war files
- delete the extracted folder
- adjust file settings (tomcat user)
- start tomcat9 service

Up to now we faced no more freezes.
So i suggest that hot deployment on tomcat9 (maybe in conjunction with java11 being also updated) causes freezes.

This solution is working for us.